# VIM substitute match patterns on beginning and end of header

Tags: vim, substitution

I need to clean a long document. Someone put square brackets on each line starting with '§'. I need to get rid of them to clean paragraph headers. Here is my perl way:

```
cat messy_doc |perl -pe 's/^\s+§/§/g;  if (/^§/) {s/\[//g; s/\]$//g}' > clean_doc
```

Any hint how to do this in VI[M] straight away?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: does "put square brackets on" mean `[§the line content]` or `§[the line content]`?

Comment: the second one
§ [the line content]

sometimes there is ^\s+§\s+[the line content]$